# Run program without form on windows startup

Tags: vb.net

What basically i want is to show is:

> notifyicon.visible = true

I mean to show a tray icon when the windows starts up but the program form should not be shown ,how could i achieve it ?

I got to know that by adding to registry you can run the program on startup example below

```
Dim regkey As RegistryKey
        regkey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", True)
        If (runonstartupToolStripMenuItem.Checked = True) Then
            ' Add the value in the registry so that the application runs at startup
            regkey.SetValue("Your Application Name", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString())
        Else
            ' Remove the value from the registry so that the application doesn't start
            regkey.DeleteValue("Your Application Name", False)
        End If
```

but this will run the whole program and will make form show up which i do not want unless user manually starts it.

Comment: You would need to have your application accept at least one commandline argument that you can read and then decide whether to display a form or not.  You would include that argument in the commandline that you store in the Registry.

Comment: could you show me the example

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your form:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      Me.Hide()                    ' <= Required
      Me.ShowInTaskbar = False     ' <= Required
      NotifyIcon1.Visible = True  
      NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(10000)
 End Sub
```

When the program opens when the windows starts it should open with a unique parameter,
And when the unique parameter is found the form will be hidden,
Conversely if the user opens the program, will not have the parameter and then the form can show.

Comment: what about when user run the app manually it will load and form and which will call me.hide() will not open the form and user has to open from notifyicon which does not seems appropriate,atleast it should open form when use open it manually and by both ways it will call event of form.load

Comment: Hide() in the load event does not hide a form.  Easy to find out, just try it.

Comment: @HansPassant `Hide()` with `ShowInTaskbar = False` does the work.

Comment: Well, that's a pretty nasty hack.  Do beware the side-effects.

Comment: @HansPassant Why `is a pretty nasty hack`? After all, we really do not want to see the form on the taskbar.

Answer (score 0):

I am use checkbox to set and unset:

```
Private Sub cbStartup_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbStartup.CheckedChanged
        Dim applicationName As String = Application.ProductName
        Dim applicationPath As String = Application.ExecutablePath

        If cbStartup.Checked = True Then
            Dim regKey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
            regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True)
            regKey.SetValue(applicationName, """" & applicationPath & """")
            regKey.Close()
        Else
            Dim regKey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
            regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True)
            regKey.DeleteValue(applicationName, False)
            regKey.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Test working on VS 2015 run on Windows 10 64Bit.